# WPF Regex special character '&' incorrect syntax

Tags: regex, wpf

In my WPF application I want to validate email with this conditions.

The local part can be up to 64 characters in length and consist of any combination of alphabetic characters, digits, or any of the following special characters: ! # $ % & ‘ * + – / = ? ^ _ ` . { | } ~.

My Regex is
[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%'*+–=?^_`.{|}~/&]{1,64}@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}

But when i use '&' character it shows the following error

Expected the following token: ";".

Comment: Can you show how you are setting or using that Regex string in code? If this is in the XAML code, '&' has special meaning and needs to be replaced with "&amp;" to display it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my solution.

I had to use ***&amp*;**
and
My final Regex is

> [^.][a-zA-Z0-9!#$%'*+=?^_`.{|}~-/**&amp**;]{1,64}@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-use-special-characters-in-xaml